# Spacing between flex elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLoyr0oe/1/)

I have a list displayed with flex:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    ....

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: gold;
}

li{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    background:grey;
 }
```

Now I want some space between my li elements, adding margin or padding pushes the elements on to the next line (I want flex wrap for when I have more than 4 elements).

I know the above can be solved with box sizing, but my main problem is that I want spacing between the elements, but with the first and last element to line up to the left and right side of the parent element.

How can this be achieved?

eg.

```
|li|spacing|li|spacing|li|spacing|li|
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great resource

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this out- I used `calc` to adjust the `flex-basis` to allow custom `margin`s that you can distribute for the `ul` (used `justify-content: space-between` for distributing that margin).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: gold;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
li {
  flex-basis: calc(25% - 20px);
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Let me know your feedback on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Pete - I think its been fixed with an edit of space-between. This looks good, thanks!

Comment: Will do when it lets me.

Comment: Awesome - this is very helpful!

Comment: Note that "IE & Edge are reported to not support calc inside a 'flex'." -- [calc() @ caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: How to do if we have unknown number of li. Lets say 2 or 5. How can we fix then space evenly?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first google result I want to add this can be accomplished with the new "gap" property:

```
ul {
    gap: 8px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution (in the generic use case):

Say you have 2 elements like below:

You can use the following css to get the same spacing between the elements.

Example:

```css
.elem1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.elem2 {
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="elem1">
        <div class="elem2">1</div>
        <div class="elem2">2</div>
        <div class="elem2">3</div>
        <div class="elem2">4</div>
    </div>
```

This achieves the same spacing on the outer border, as well as between elements (in the x or y direction) without any extra calculation.  While `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-around` can have a similar effect, it also centers everything.

React Example (with Material UI)

```
render() {
    return (
        <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" ml={1} mt={1} >
            {this.service.items().map(element =>
                <Box key={element.id} mr={1} mb={1} >
                    <Card entity={element} />
                </Box>
            )}
        </Box>
    )
}
```